# how to skip killing a process using taskkill

Tags: java, windows, cmd, taskkill

I'm using the following code to kill all java processes.

```
taskkill /F /IM javaw.exe
taskkill /F /IM java.exe
exit
```

This works fine when I need to kill all of my java processes. The problem is when I run it it also kills my eclipse process. How can I skip the eclipse process and kill all other java processes.

Comment: You can't really since both of them use Java...
(Assuming, you're using Java as well on Eclipse)

Comment: you need some equivalent to Unix's `pgrep` I guess

Answer (score 0):

One way is to save the PID of the eclipse process and then when you taskkill all java processes, you exclude that PID

adapted from [Kill only one process with taskkill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196731/kill-only-one-process-with-taskkill):

in one `cmd` window:

Start eclipse using a batchfile:

```
start eclipse.exe
for /f "tokens=2" %%x in ('tasklist ^| findstr java.exe') do set PIDTOSAVE=%%x
```

and terminate you would use

```
for /f "tokens=2" %%x in ('tasklist ^| findstr java.exe ^| findstr /v %PIDTOSAVE%') do taskkill /F /PID %%x
```

Another way I found was to use the `jps` program that comes bundled with the JDK, to find java processes by name. See http://yannickloriot.com/2012/08/kill-a-java-process-from-the-command-line-or-a-bat-file/#sthash.bFaaPUxi.dpbs. Example usage would be:

```
for /f "tokens=1" %i in ('jps -m ^| find "YOUR_JAVA_PROCESS_NAME"') do ( taskkill /F /PID %i )
```

The best way for you will depend on your specific usecase.