# Batch file check if a program is running only once and close duplicate instances or launch it if none is running

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to realize a batch file that checks if a program is running and if not launch it, and more if is it launched more than one time close all the duplicate instances.
this is the code I implemented using also some tips found here in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196731/kill-only-one-process-with-taskkill):

```
:check
tasklist /fi "imagename eq notepad.exe" /nh |find /i /c "notepad.exe" > "%temp%\variable.txt" #here I count how many instances are running 
set /p value=<"%temp%\variable.txt"  #and save the value in the variable.txt file
##check and choose action
if %value% equ nul goto none
if %value% geq 2 goto more
if %value% equ 1 goto one

:more
for /f "tokens=2" %%x in ('tasklist ^| findstr notepad.exe') do set PIDTOKILL=%%x
taskkill /F /PID %PIDTOKILL%
goto check

:none
start notepad.exe
goto check

:one
timeout 10 > nul
goto check
```

But some strange behavior happens when I test it...
if only one instances is running all fine, but if I close notepad while the batch file is running the routine goes to the :more label apparently without any reason...what I'm doing wrong?
thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stupid error ... this is the working code:

```
:check
timeout 10 > nul
tasklist /fi "imagename eq notepad.exe" /nh |find /i /c "notepad.exe" > "%temp%\variable.txt"
set /p value=<"%temp%\variable.txt"

if %value% equ 0 goto none
if %value% geq 2 goto more
if %value% equ 1 goto check

:more
for /f "tokens=2" %%x in ('tasklist ^| findstr notepad.exe') do set PIDTOKILL=%%x
taskkill /F /PID %PIDTOKILL%
goto check

:none
start notepad.exe
goto check
```